# How do I replace another linux distro (eOS) with Ubuntu?

Tags: system-installation

I have Elementary OS luna (12.04 based distro) distro installed on my dual boot (Win 8.1) laptop. I booted up a live USB of 14.04 but unfortunately I don't get a straight up simple option of replacing the eOS set up completely. So I guess I have to manually install in under `something else` install option.

How do I go about this as I don't want to mess anything up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right with 'Something else' option. But you will have to boot the live DVD or the USB version with Ubuntu 14.04, and after you are in the live session you can setup your internet connection and start the installer from the live desktop.

Once you are facing the window presenting those options for installing Ubuntu, you choose the last one **Something else** and press Next to get to your hard disk partition table. You need to format to Linux ext4 that partition where you previously installed Luna OS, and preserve the Linux swap area assuming it is still present in your list.

Or you can delete the partition where you installed Linux before and create a new partition formatted as Linux ext4 choosing the foreslash **/** as mount or startup point for this partition. You also need a small linux swap partition (1-2 GB) but I suppose it is still there from your previous installation.

And when you are done, you can select your newly formatted linux ext4 partition and press NEXT to begin installing Ubuntu. During installation you will have to provide the installer with your desired keyboard layout, your location (for setting up time and date) and some username and password. Fill in every requirement with patience so you won't have to start the installer again.